# What do amps mean?

Tags: power-supply

I have a laptop that is 110v-240v with 6.32a. I am going out of the country and can only find adapters that say 100v-250v with a 2.5a max. What impact will this have on running my computer? Or is there an adapter that matches the amps I have?

Comment: What type of adapter are you referring to?

Comment: It's a travel adapter, specifically Targus World Power Travel Adapter

Comment: Normally you should get an adapter that has an ampere rating at least as high as the equipment states. Anything less and you may not be able to power up the device, or it may start behaving badly.

Comment: http://science.howstuffworks.com/environmental/energy/question501.htm - Without enough amps your laptop will not be able to draw enough power to charge.

Comment: -1 surely you should know that amps are an electronics concept.. you don't come to a computer question site and ask an electronics question(as you have in your title),.. and the body of your question is a bit different to your title.

Comment: You're probably getting wrong answers because people are misunderstanding your question. You would have to have an incredibly massive laptop for it actually want 110v-240v with 6.32A. You are probably mixing the laptop's specifications with the specifications for its power supply. Most likely, the laptop's power supply draws *way* under 2.5A from the line, as that would be over 200 watts. What "adapters" are you talking about? Are you talking about plug adapters or power supplies?

Answer (score 2):

Your existing 110-240V power supply is designed to work in any country except Japan. Though it probably will also work in Japan as well, though it may not work at all. If it doesn't work at all it won't damage anything.

Power supplies have input and output voltages, and input and output amps maximums. 100-240V is the range of allowable input voltages. The rating of 2.5A and 6.32A is the output amps maximum allowed.

The power supply needs to be able to provide an output amps at least the output amps of the old one. 2.5A power supply is not enough to work like your old one. If the power supply is not rated for enough amps it will overheat and burn out components or it will trip the overload protection if it has one to protect itself.

When going to a country/region with a different supply voltage only the input voltage and frequency needs to be in range. 100-240V power supplies are designed to be used in any country. Japan is the only country that uses less than 110V.

There are some laptops that are able to detect what amount of power the power supply can provide and adjust its usage accordingly, by not charging the battery so fast, and not allowing the cpu to run as fast as it can.

Comment: Anecdotally but empirically, I've never had any issue in Japan with any equipment rated as 'dual voltage' even if it only said 120-240v

Comment: I'm not surprised. Due to mains power usually only being within 10% of the nominal voltage anyway, device manufacturers have to deal with that variation anyway. The difference between plugging a device expecting 120V into a mains with 100V +/- 10% outlet may work and just be more susceptible to brownouts.

Answer (score 0):

*Amps* is short for *Ampere*, which measures - in laymans terms - the amount of current or power that flows.

If you have a connection with not enough power, it will just not work or start to overheat and burn - both not recommendable.

Comment: What do you mean by "current or power"?! Current and power are completely different concepts.

Comment: Current and power are closely coupled.  Since Watts=Current * Voltage, if voltage is fixed, then current (amps) is directly proportional to power (watts).    It is thus correct to say that if the connection does not have enough current it will not work..., and the same thing can be said if it does not have enough power.  I do agree this is not a great answer though.

Comment: @davidgo -- Just because there's a mathematical relationship does not mean that you can interchange the words.  (velocity)=(distance)/(time), so if a policeman ask you "do you know how fast you were driving?", are you going to reply with a distance or time value?  It's because of ignorance about the proper meaning of these electrical terms that sloppy explanations exist.

Comment: @sawdust - conversely I would have a poorer understanding of the world around me if the smart guys who can handle the maths did not oversimplify the results to a level I can grasp.   The OP did say "In laymans terms".  (and if a policeman asks me how fast I was driving It would be foolish to reply, although if I were pushed, I would attempt to say that I was at XXX location XXX km's away at YYYY time, which could both answer and be more likely to evidence then an instantaneous speed - and less likely to incriminate me)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz , I tried to make the answer simple so a non-electrician can understand it. As end-users typically have no control over the voltage and it is constant and given, the current is a direct measure for the power used. I could have written it more 'correct', but I doubt it would have been more helpful for the asker.

Comment: @Aganju Sorry, but that's nonsense. A common mistake, for example, is seeing that your laptop requires 3A and thinking a power supply with a maximum input current of 0.5A won't be able to power it. End users and non-electricians absolutely do need to understand that amps don't measure power.